# Adicionar footer com xhtml2pdf em páginas especificas com Django

Tags: html, css, python, django

Eu tenho um footer padrão que é exibido em algumas páginas ao gerar o PDF com o **xhtml2pdf** usando o Django que deve ser posicionado no final da página. Porém em algumas eu não quero exibir. Com o código atual eu consigo posicionar no fim da página. Porém, quando é aplicado em todas elas. Como eu faço pra posicionar o footer no final da página e não aplicar em todas na hora de gerar o PDF?

style do xhtm2pdf:

```
 @page {
    size: a4 portrait;
    @frame content_frame {
        left: 25pt; width: 550pt; top: 10pt; height: 850pt;
    }
    @frame footer_frame {
        -pdf-frame-content: footer_content;
        left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 750pt; height: 200pt;
    }
}
```

Footer:

```
<div id="footer_content">
<hr>
<p align="center">
    www.site.com.br <br/>

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi, o que deseja fazer é inserir um footer especifico nas paginas que podem ser reenderizadas como PDF, correto?

Se for isso mesmo, você pode usar `{% include %}` e `{% if %}` dentro dos `templates` do Django. Com essas duas `template tags` e variavies de contexto que são passadas da `view` para o `template`, você consegue validar uma condição e incluir o footer dinamicamente nas paginas que devem ter o mesmo.

- Mais sobre os [tempates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/)
- Mais sobre [template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/)
- Mais sobre [contextos](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Context) e [views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/views/)

Caso não seja isso que deseja pode tentar editar a pergunta, incluindo mais exemplos de código, ou até mesmo tentar explicar de uma forma mais direta para que talvez seja possivel a comunidade reproduzir.

Espero ter ajudado!